# Telerik RadGridView row in edit mode is not committed on lost focus

Tags: c#, .net, wpf, telerik, radgridview

I'm using Telerik's RadGridView in an MVVM app. In this particular gridview users can add rows and edit them. There's also a separate save button to save the items in the RadGridView.

The problem that I'm experiencing is that when the user inserts a new row, but doesn't press ENTER or ESC to cancel or commit, then clicks on the Save button, the bound collection is in a half-baked state. My preferred behavior would be for the gridview to commit the row edit whenever the user clicks anywhere outside of the row being edited. Is that possible?

Answer (score 1):

Turns out it's a simple line of code that can solve this. I eventually was able to solve this myself by placing the following in the event that is triggered when clicking the save button:

```
gridview.CommitRowEdit(gridview.RowInEditMode);
```

It takes the current row that's being edited and commits it.

Comment: The edit should be commited on lost focus by default. Maybe you changed the ActionOnLostFocus property of the Radgridview ? : https://docs.telerik.com/devtools/wpf/controls/radgridview/how-to/cancel-edit-on-lost-focus

Comment: oddly enough, having ActionOnLostFocus not specified or set as CommitEdit dit not resolve the issue in my case.